# Looping through table data React JS

Tags: reactjs

How can I loop through local JSON data in React JS and return data within the td tags?

Example from JSON file:

```
[
{
    "organize": true,
    "sender": "Dach Group",
    "domain": "godfrey.name",
    "email": "Mercedes.OKon@gmail.com",
    "folder": "Business"
},
{
    "organize": true,
    "sender": "Bernhard and Sons",
    "domain": "torey.net",
    "email": "Zack45@yahoo.com",
    "folder": "Home"
},
{
}
```

console log is logging all the data so it is definitely grabbing and showing the data with the for loop.

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
 import './TableHeader.css';
 import localdata from './data';

class TableHeader extends Component {
   render() {

   for(var i = 0; i < localdata.length; i++) {
   var obj = localdata[i];

   console.log(obj.organize + ", " + obj.sender + ", " + obj.domain + ", " + obj.email + ", " + obj.folder);
   }

return (
  <div className="container">

    <table className="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style={{height: '50px'}}>Organize</th>
            <th style={{height: '50px'}}>Sender</th>
            <th style={{height: '50px'}}>Domain</th>
            <th style={{height: '50px'}}>Email</th>
            <th style={{height: '50px'}}>Folder</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
              <input type="checkbox" name="" value="" />
            </td>

            <td style={{backgroundColor: 'white'}}>
              {obj.sender}
            </td>


            <td style={{backgroundColor: 'white'}}>{obj.domain}</td>
            <td style={{backgroundColor: 'white'}}>{obj.email}</td>
            <td style={{backgroundColor: 'white'}} className="bordercolor">
              <select style={{height: '30px', width: '100%'}}>
                <option>Travel</option>
                <option>Shopping</option>
                <option>Finance</option>
              </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>

    </table>
  </div>
);
}
}

export default TableHeader;
```

Answer (score 2):

Using map is an efficient way to do this:

```
var tableData = localdata.map(function(obj) {
 return <tr><td>{obj.organizer}</td><td>{obj.sender}</td></tr>
}
```

Then in your render function

```
<tbody>
  {tableData}
</tbody>
```

Although, a cleaner implementation would be to pull the row into its own component that takes an object and returns a row, then your map would just have to pass the "obj" into that component and it would return the  and populated 's.

Comment: Why are you using a template string for the HTML markup? OP is using JSX.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your render logic in a loop as well. I made an example with your data

```js
class HelloWorld extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const data = [
      {
          "organize": true,
          "sender": "Dach Group",
          "domain": "godfrey.name",
          "email": "Mercedes.OKon@gmail.com",
          "folder": "Business"
      },
      {
          "organize": true,
          "sender": "Bernhard and Sons",
          "domain": "torey.net",
          "email": "Zack45@yahoo.com",
          "folder": "Home"
      },
    ];

    return (
      <div>
         <table className="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style={{height: '50px'}}>Organize</th>
                <th style={{height: '50px'}}>Sender</th>
                <th style={{height: '50px'}}>Domain</th>
                <th style={{height: '50px'}}>Email</th>
                <th style={{height: '50px'}}>Folder</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {data.map(obj => {
              return (
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="" value="" />
                  </td>
                  <td style={{backgroundColor: 'white'}}>
                    {obj.sender}
                  </td>
                  <td style={{backgroundColor: 'white'}}>{obj.domain}</td>
                  <td style={{backgroundColor: 'white'}}>{obj.email}</td>
                  <td style={{backgroundColor: 'white'}} className="bordercolor">
                    <select style={{height: '30px', width: '100%'}}>
                      <option>Travel</option>
                      <option>Shopping</option>
                      <option>Finance</option>
                    </select>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              );
            })}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<HelloWorld />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It says TypeError: data.map is not a function, any suggestions please

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `obj` variable is locally scoped to the `for` loop, and hence when you try and access `obj.domain` for example in the JSX, `obj` resolves to undefined.

I suppose you want to display a new `<tr>` for each item in the JSON, which you can do with Javascript's [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
<tbody>
  { localdata.map(obj => {
      return (
        <tr key={ obj.domain }>
          <td>{ obj.domain }</td>
        </tr>
       );
     }) 
  }
</tbody>
```

Note that without the `key` prop at the top-level React element in the mapped array, React will throw a warning that all items in an array must have unique keys.

---

Do read React's documentation on [Lists and Keys](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html) to get used to the usage of `map()` which is widely used in React, as well as the significance of unique `key`s for each element.

I also recommend reading [React.js and Dynamic Children - Why the Keys are Important](http://blog.arkency.com/2014/10/react-dot-js-and-dynamic-children-why-the-keys-are-important/), which showcases an example of hidden bugs which can arise when your use case gets more complicated.

Comment: Thanks for the help!