# How to loop data and print in a table using material ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am working with `Material-UI` and getting data from the backend. There is no issue with the backend, but I don't know how to loop data and print it in a table format using `Material-UI`.
Can anyone guide me on how to print data in a table format?

Here is my code so far:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { getProducts } from "../../services/products";
import MaterialTable, { MTableToolbar } from "material-table";

const productsList = props => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [state] = React.useState({
    columns: [
      { title: "Brand", field: "brand" }, //assume here my backend schema is brand
      { title: "Price", field: "price" }, //here price
      { title: "Model no", field: "model" } //here model
    ]
  });

  const getProducts = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await getProducts();
      setData(res.data);
      console.log(res.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getProducts();
  }, []);

  return (
    <MaterialTable
      components={{
        Toolbar: props => {
          return (
            <div>
              <MTableToolbar {...props} />
            </div>
          );
        }
      }}
      options={{
        actionsColumnIndex: 5,
        selection: true
      }}
    />
  );
};
export default function Company() {
  return <productsList />;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Looping through table data React JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43241139/looping-through-table-data-react-js)

Comment: Hi @minus I have seen your link in that example, you are using bootstrap but in my scenario I am using Material ui so please tell me how to loop data in Material ui

Comment: Are you using the library [material-table](https://material-table.com/#/) or the [Table component](https://material-ui.com/components/tables/) from Material-UI?

Comment: I am using library material-tabel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the `data` and `columns` value. So try it like this:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import MaterialTable, { MTableToolbar } from "material-table";

const fakeFetch = () => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    resolve({
      data: [
        { brand: "brand 1", price: 1, model: "123" },
        { brand: "brand 2", price: 1, model: "456" },
        { brand: "brand 3", price: 1, model: "789" }
      ]
    });
  });
};

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  // When the columns don't change you don't need to hold it in state
  const columns = [
    { title: "Brand", field: "brand" }, //assume here my backend schema is brand
    { title: "Price", field: "price" }, //here price
    { title: "Model no", field: "model" } //here model
  ];

  const getProducts = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await fakeFetch();
      setData(res.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getProducts();
  }, []);

  return (
    <MaterialTable
      columns={columns}  // <-- Set the columns on the table
      data={data}        // <-- Set the data on the table
      components={{
        Toolbar: props => {
          return (
            <div>
              <MTableToolbar {...props} />
            </div>
          );
        }
      }}
      options={{
        actionsColumnIndex: 5,
        selection: true
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

To make it even easier you could also provide your fetch function (`fakeFetch` in this case) as the data value;

```js
data={fakeFetch} // <-- Using this you wouldn't need the [data, setData], getProducts and useEffect code.
```

[Working sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/spring-pine-6h5bg?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Answer (score 0):

As per the material-table approach, you have to put your whole fetched data on the `data` prop inside the `MaterialTable` component. So as far as I can understand, there is no looping made in this case by using the material-table library.

Assuming the attributes in your data object match the field names specified in your `columns` prop (if not, create an array of objects from your fetched data that matches the column fields or vice-versa).

And the code would be just the addition of the `data` prop in your table:

```
<MaterialTable
  // ... existing props
  data={data}
/>
```

Keep in mind that you could also use the [remote data](https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/remote-data) approach as described in the documentation which gives you the means to immediately query your data and fetch it inside the `data` prop of the table.